# Как в этой программе работает декремент e--?

Tags: java

Программа на консоли выдает такой результат:

```
2 в степени 0 равно 1
2 в степени 1 равно 2
2 в степени 2 равно 4
2 в степени 3 равно 8
2 в степени 4 равно 16
```

`e--` закрыто в блоке кода `while` - соответственно выйти за пределы своего блока вверх, туда где `e = i` она не может. Соответственно переменной `e` вверху каждый раз присваивается значение `i`, спущенное сверху.
Но тогда получается что декремент `e--` вообще не нужен и его можно убрать? Я его убираю и программа на вывод выводит только одну верхнюю строку... (2 в степени 0 равно 1),
то есть цикл `for` вообще перестает работать
Почему так происходит? Как тут срабатывает декремент `e--`? Зачем он тут нужен?

```
public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int e;
        int result;

        for(int i=0; i < 5; i++) {
            result = 1;
            e = i;
            while(e > 0) {
                result *=2; //КАК ТУТ РЕЗАЛТ ВЫРАСТАЕТ В ОТВЕТЕ ЗАДАЧИ ЕСЛИ ТУТ ВСЕГДА 1*2 = 2 И БЕЗ ВАРИАНТОВ
                e--;
            }
            System.out.println("2 в степени " + i + " равно " + result);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `e-- закрыто в блоке кода while` - не закрыто. Переменная e объявлена на верхнем уровне метода, во всех блоках в этом методе идет работа именно с это переменной. `e--` не закрыто в блоке `while`, а изменяет переменную, объявленную как `int e;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Довольно странная программа. То, что она делает, можно успешно заменить следующим кодом:

```
for(int i = 0, result = 1; i < 5; i++, result = 1) {
    for(int e = 0; e < i; e++){
        result *= 2;
    }
    System.out.println("2 в степени " + i + " равно " + result);
}
```

По-сути
и

```
for(int e = 0; e < i; e++){
    result *= 2;
}
```

,и

```
e = i;
while(e > 0) {
    result *=2;
    e--;
}
```

,и

```
e = 0;
while(e < i) {
    result *=2;
    e++;
}
```

одно и то же. `e` лишь играет роль счетчика - счетчика, который гарантирует выполнение операции `result *= 2` ровно `i` раз.

Answer (score 0):

Там не 1*2, а 1*2*2*.. столько раз, чему равно `i` (т.е. `е`).